# How to render dynamically added component in Vue like angular's compile function

Tags: vue.js

I wonder how can I achieve a simple tooltip component in Vue?

What I try to do is: Hover on element, a component tag will be appended.

I do not know how to compile/render that component into DOM after I append it using  jquery. In Angular, this can be achieved by using `$compile`

This way to implement tooltip may not be a good practice, but I just wonder how to achieve.

Thanks,

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44372419/3412322

Comment: @DanielBeck Thanks, how did you find that post? I do not know what keyword to search

Comment: That was one of the two questions I've ever asked here, so pretty easy for me to find ;)

Comment: @DanielBeck Thanks.